# Imported function in a specific file returns TypeError: X is not a function but it works in other files

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, methods, import

I'm using Node.JS 12 LTS

There is file named CompanyUtil.js and another file named ScrapNames.js

In ScrapNames.js - I have exported multiple methods using module.exports = { ParseName: ParseName, etc } syntax and imported ParseName method to CompanyUtil.js

The exported ParseName method is an async function inside ScrapNames.js

CompanyUtil.js outputs TypeError: ParseName is not a function when it trying to execute ParseName method; however, the same ParseName method works in other files that I tested.

Function import syntax I used:

```
const { ParseName } = require('./ScrapNames.js')
```

And here is how I call it once imported:

```
async function main() {
 let name = await ParseName("Steve Jobs")
 return name
}
```

So far, I have restarted my computer and deleted CompanyUtil.js and re-added it but no luck.

I need to add that ScrapNames.js also uses three methods from CompanyUtil.js

Is this has to do with the CompanyUtil Name? Perhaps Circular Dependency?

What surprise me that this method worked on that file this morning and the ScrapNames.js had only about two methods references to CompanyUtil.js but while in this afternoon I added more references and it broke the app.

Comment: Can you add example how are you importing the function, and how are you calling it?

Comment: @Berislav Kovacki Done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can confirm this issue is caused by circular dependencies. I refactored the whole code and moved NameParse method into an independent module; now everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is one thing that I have not seen, did you require the the  ScrapNames.js file after exporting to CompanyUtil.js.

If you haven't done so try doing it as this may the cause (I think). Again you naming convention you should not start the first letter of the file name with a capital letter.

A code snippet will be more comprehensive to tackle your problem.

Comment: I do use Require. See above.

Answer (score 0):

From your code try using;

const ParseName = require('./ScrapNames.js')

instead of 
const { ParseName } = require('./ScrapNames.js')